# Pulling Data in to Excel from SQL Server 2012 and formatting it

Tags: excel, excel-2010, export-to-excel

I will try and explain as best I can what i am trying to do but I am no Excel genius :-)

I have 1 Excel Sheet which we will call Template this is going to be pre-populated with data and then used offline, I am going to import a Data Set in to a tab called RawData from SQL Server, data set will be something similar to this

Description     Rate     Hours     SellValue     Item

APU             2.50     3         7.50          1
APU             2.50     4         10.00         2
APU             2.50     5         12.50         3
INS             2.50     3         7.50          1
INS             2.50     4         10.00         2
INS             2.50     5         12.50         3

There could be more or less records but no more than 7 distinct descriptions.

There is now another Tab called Report

At Position A1 will be the Title APU then underneath that I want the records with the Description APU to appear and this block will shrink and expand depending on the number of records.  Then wherever the last record appears will be the next heading INS and the records associated with that description.  There is one final tab called Rate and at position A1 will be a rate value, when this is changed, it will take the new rate value and re-calculate the SaleValue in RawData thus amending the figures in the Report.  I am sure there are better ways to explain this but I hope someone has got the gist before I loose what hair I have left.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and powerful approach to such problems would be to use Pivot-Tables in excel. You can customize your data view better.

Comment: Hi xtechkid, thanks for the reply, looking at how complex the report format is I am not sure if Pivot Tables would be able to help, let alone me trying to use them in this way.  As i think I said, I have the report template it just seems that I have to work out a way of putting the data in to the places that I want it to go, though I am sure I am over simplifying it.